# Giving array as parameter using redirect()

Tags: yii2

I fail giving an array as parameter using method redirect() getting following Exception

```
Bad request(404):
Invalid data for parameter "Mailadresses"
```

`var_dump` on `$Mailadresses` shows this:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => string(22) "goetz.bewerber@gmx.net" 
    [1] => string(25) "zetkin.bewerber@gmail.com"
}
```

It depends on the users choice, how many elements will be an array, so I am not able to put the extra item(s) as a parameter in the array

Any ideas, how to give an array as a parameter to actionMethod in Controller?
Here is code:

```
return $this->redirect(['/mail/mail-ausgang/stapelmail', 
'IdPerson' => $id_person, 
'Mailadresses' => $Mailadresses]);
```

P.S.: If my intention can't be implemented using `redirect()`, which method should be used? Note, that actionMethod is in another class

**Rephrasing question:**
I want to achieve sending emails from class MailAusgangController. Mail addresses are in the database and will be collected from class `BewerberController` by Users choice through CheckboxColumns. CheckboxColumns will give me id respectively Mailadresses. Class `MailAusgangController` doesn't know anything about this, that's why I have to give this information as an array

Here is a code of redirecting-class

```
    public function actionCollectMailAdresses() {
        $session = new Session();
        $Mailadresses = array();
        $x = 0;
        try {
            $checkbox = (array) Yii::$app->request->post('selection');
            if (empty(($checkbox)) && (isset($_POST['button_checkBoxes']))) {
                $session->addFlash("warning", "Selektieren Sie die Bewerber, für die Mails erstellt werden sollen, über die Checkboxen");
                return $this->redirect(['/bewerber/bewerber/index']);
            }
            /* checkBox enthält die Id */
            foreach ($checkbox as $item) {
                $id_person = Bewerber::findOne(['id' => $item])->id_person;
                $IdEKontakt = EKontakt::findOne(['id_person' => $id_person])->id;
                $mailAdress = KontaktMail::findOne(['id_e_kontakt' => $IdEKontakt]);
                if (empty($mailAdress)) {
                    $session->addFlash("warning", "Für mindestens einer der Bewerber ist im System keine Mailadresse hinterlegt.<br>Überprüfen Sie bitte die Tabellenspalte Bewerber/Kandidat auf Mailadressen");
                    return $this->redirect(['/bewerber/bewerber/index']);
                } else {
                    $mailAdress = KontaktMail::findOne(['id_e_kontakt' => $IdEKontakt])->mail;
                    $Mailadresses[$x] = $mailAdress;
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            return $this->redirect(['/mail/mail-ausgang/stapelmail', 'Mailadresses' => $Mailadresses]);
        } catch (\Exception $error) {
            $go_back = "/bewerber/bewerber/index";
            error_handling::error_without_id($error, $go_back);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to do why passing the action parameter as array whereas you cant do this you can send the parameter either as `string` url or an `array` in the format of `[$route, ...name-value pairs...]` (e.g. `['site/index', 'ref' => 1]`) `yii\helpers\Url::to()` will be used to convert the array into a URL.

Comment: can you add your action `stapelmail` too and add some description what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It depends of users choice, how many elements will be in array

Comment: that is not helping to understand until you add the relevant code for the action in which this redirect is and the action that you are redirecting to

Comment: Code is to large to publish. Hope, rephrasing question helps understand my intention??

Comment: Just added  relevant code for redirecting

Comment: and why have you used that function as action do you want to display these emails there using view ?

Comment: between you can use `Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error','you have an error')` directly rather than using the `new Session()`

Comment: Yes. User should have possibility to change values in formular before sending mail(s). Any ideas how to achieve my intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by my own:
As it is not possible giving complex datatypes using method `redirect()`, I decided using SESSION in order to get an array in class `MailausgangController`.
Here is code(in `BewerberController`:)

```
   $sessionPHP = Yii::$app->session;
   $sessionPHP->open();
   $sessionPHP['var'] = $Mailadresses;
   return $this->redirect(['/mail/mail-ausgang/stapelmail']);
```

and in MailAusgangController:

```
 $session = Yii::$app->session;
 $session->open();
 $quelladresse = $session['var'];
 var_dump($quelladresse);
 die();
```

`var_dump` will show me adresses as expected